# Send anonymous email

Tags: webapp-rec, privacy, anonymous

Is there a service that would allow one to send anonymous emails?

Or, if not anonymous, one that would create a temporary email address?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I used a couple of times [10 Minute Mail](http://10minutemail.com) service.

Just found another useful service that allows you to create a temporary email alias: [tempalias](http://tempalias.com).

Answer (score 3):

How about [Hushmail](http://www.hushmail.com/)?

> Hushmail offers private, secure free email accounts. Email is
>   encrypted and spam/virus scanned.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know [AKA-Post](http://akapost.com/) does a similiar thing.

> With akapost you can send and receive
>   email from your existing email
>   account, but still keep your actual
>   email address private.

Plus: No costs for you, booya!

Answer (score -1):

Just because it isn't your email, doesn't mean it is anonymous. The email headers most likely will still be included from what I can tell which will include the server it was sent from, etc. The website probably keeps track of its visitors and there is still traceability.